# MySQL - How do I select most recent row for a particular user ID, based on the product type purchased (in a query that wont take too long to run)?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a database I'm trying to run a query on:

Table 1 contains the product ID and the type of product it is (e.g. product IDs 1 & 2 are 'lawnmowers', product IDs 3 & 4 are 'leafblowers')

Table 2 contains the user purchases, which has a product ID column (but not product type). Product ID corresponds to the first table. Each user has the same user_ID across multiple purchases, but also a unique purchase ID.

I am trying to run a query on product types (e.g. lawnmower), to get all of the people who bought lawnmowers, and then remove duplicates for people who bought multiple lawnmowers (I want only the latest purchase for each person). So I want to filter by user_id and only use the maximum value for purchase id (the latest one).

This is where I'm at so far with the query - it's currently not running as I think it's taking too long (I'm not getting any syntax errors):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM purchases
 WHERE product_id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM [database_name].products
    WHERE product_type="lawnmowers"
 )
 AND purchase_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(puchase_id)
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY user_id
 )
```

Does anyone know an alternative query that will run a bit faster and will achieve the results I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want this query.  Try joining the `purchases` table to a subquery which identifies the latest lawnmower purchase, for each user.

```
SELECT *
FROM purchases t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p1.user_id, MAX(p1.purchase_id) AS max_purchase_id
    FROM purchases p1
    INNER JOIN products p2
        ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id
    WHERE p2.product_type = 'lawnmowers'
    GROUP BY p1.user_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.purchase_id = t2.max_purchase_id;
```

Note that while this should return the latest lawnmower purchase for each user, it *won't* report users who never made a lawnmower purchase.  If you have the requirement to report on all users, then you should probably have a separate user table which can be used for joining here.

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks to be what I'm after :)

Comment: My client has just asked to add another condition to this in terms of removing duplicates - from table 2, they'd like to remove anyone who has the same fields for first_name, last_name, and company_name (keeping only the one with the highest purchase_id). Does anyone know how I might tweak the existing query to run this check after/while removing the first set of duplicates?

Comment: @psm_344 You should open a new question, and this sounds like a substantially different query than what you originally needed.

Comment: Thank you, have started a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752826/mysql-how-do-i-select-most-recent-row-for-a-particular-user-id-and-filter-out