# MySQL - How do I select most recent row for a particular user ID (and filter out duplicates), based on the product type purchased?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database I'm running a query on:

Table 1 contains the product ID and the type of product it is (e.g. product IDs 1 & 2 are 'lawnmowers', product IDs 3 & 4 are 'leafblowers')

Table 2 contains the user purchases, which has a product ID column (but not product type). Product ID corresponds to the first table. Each user has the same user_ID across multiple purchases, but also a unique purchase ID. This table also contains user data such as first_name, last_name, and company.

I am running a query on product types (e.g. lawnmower), to get all of the people who bought lawnmowers, and then remove duplicate users for people who bought multiple lawnmowers (I want only the latest purchase for each person). I'm filtering by user_id and only using the maximum value for purchase id (the latest one).

This is where the query is at:

```
SELECT *
FROM purchases t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p1.user_id, MAX(p1.purchase_id) AS max_purchase_id
    FROM purchases p1
    INNER JOIN products p2
        ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id
    WHERE p2.product_type = 'lawnmowers'
    GROUP BY p1.user_id
) t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.purchase_id = t2.max_purchase_id;
```

This query is filtering out duplicate user_ids, however I'm also needing to filter out people who have the same data in first_name, last_name, and company in table 2 with different user_ids (keeping only the latest). How do I modify the existing query to filter out this data?

Sample data table 1 (before running query):

```
| product_id    | product       | 
| ------------- | ------------- | 
| 1             | lawnmower     | 
| 2             | lawnmower     | 
| 3             | leafblower    | 
| 4             | leafblower    |
```

Sample data table 2 (before running query):

```
| purchase_id   | product_id | user_id       | first_name  | last_name | company     |   
| ------------- | -----------| ------------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 1             | 1          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 2             | 2          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 3             | 1          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 4             | 2          | 790           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 5             | 1          | 800           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 6             | 2          | 800           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 7             | 1          | 900           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 8             | 4          | 800           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 9             | 4          | 800           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 10            | 4          | 900           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 11            | 1          | 950           | Bobby       | Smith     | Cook with B |
```

Current output:

```
| purchase_id   | product_id | user_id       | first_name  | last_name | company     |   
| ------------- | -----------| ------------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 3             | 1          | 777           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 4             | 2          | 790           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 9             | 4          | 800           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 10            | 4          | 900           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 11            | 1          | 950           | Bobby       | Smith     | Cook with B |
```

Expected output:

```
| purchase_id   | product_id | user_id       | first_name  | last_name | company     |   
| ------------- | -----------| ------------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- |
| 4             | 2          | 790           | Sally       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 7             | 1          | 900           | Billy       | Smith     | My Homeware |
| 11            | 1          | 950           | Bobby       | Smith     | Cook with B |
```

Comment: Can you also add some sample data, current output and expected output

Comment: @SudiptaMondal have added table data

Comment: It really is simpler to provide CREATE and INSERT statements

Comment: What is the logic by which the duplicates are being removed?  To your sample data as an example, your current output has 2 Sally Smith records.  What is the logic by which one record is removed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - At the moment, there are 2 Sally Smith records because we are only filtering out duplicates that have the same user_id. However I'm wanting to also filter out duplicates across user_ids that have the same data in fields for first_name, last_name, and company (which would leave me with the data in 'expected output'.